# probabilty proof question

Tags: probability

How do I prove the following:

1. $\operatorname{Pr}(A \cup B \cup C) = \operatorname{Pr}(A) + \operatorname{Pr}(B) + \operatorname{Pr}(C) $ 
   $\qquad − \operatorname{Pr}(A \cap B) − \operatorname{Pr}(A \cap C) − \operatorname{Pr}(B \cap C) + \operatorname{Pr}(A \cap B \cap C)$?
2. $\max( \operatorname{Pr}(A), \operatorname{Pr}(B)) \leq \operatorname{Pr} (A \cup B)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I understand the logic but im having trouble with the formality of the answer.

Comment: Can you show us what you do have, so that we can comment on it? Where, specifically, are your concerns with the formality?

Comment: 1. This is known as the inclusion/exclusion principle.

Comment: regarding questin 2 : i know that pr(A)>=0 and pr(AUB)=pr(A)+pr(B)-A union B

Comment: In your last comment, that should be $A \cap B$—that is, "$A$ *intersect* $B$," not "$A$ union $B$."

Comment: right. sorry . How do I formalize the answer?

Comment: Regarding (2), you can write it as $$P(A\cup B) = P(A\cup (B\setminus A)) = P(A) + P(B\setminus A)$$ which is the sum of probabilities of disjoint events.

Comment: Use Venn diagrams to show set relations.  The probabilities will follow trivially.

Comment: I cant use Venn diagrams, I have to use the  probailty axioms.

Comment: could someone please write a full answer for the 2nd question?